# How to make a floating Frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

For my tkinter app I want to make a frame that would on top of other widgets, not taking any space (like html position fixed).

The Frame will have to contain widgets, if Frame is not possible labels or buttons will do.

I have no idea how to do  it so haven't tried anything yet. Please help!

Comment: This sounds like one of the few cases where the `.place()` geometry manager is optimal.  Nothing else in the same container (presumably positioned via `.pack()` or `.grid()`) will care about the place'd widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demonstration of `place` manager.

Remarks in the code explain behaviour.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("868x131")
button = tk.Button(root, text="A Button")
button.place(x=2, y=2)

frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="A LabelFrame using place", bg="cyan")
# Frame using place with x, y, width, height in absolute coordinates
frame.place(x=250, y=20, width=600, height=70)

child_button = tk.Button(frame, text="A Button IN LabelFrame", bg="white")
# Note: place x,y is referenced to the container (Frame)
# Note: place uses just x,y and allows Button to determine width and height
child_button.place(x=2, y=2)

label = tk.Label(
    root,
    text="A Label on LabelFrame\nWith multiple lines\nOf Text.",
    bg="light green",
)
# Label sits on top of buttonFrame and Frame
# Note place uses just x,y and allows Label to determine width and height
label.place(x=330, y=60)

root.mainloop()
```